# UIScrollView didScroll twice after setting contentOffset with VoiceOver

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview, voiceover

Our **UIScrollView** works perfectly fine without VoiceOver, but with **VoiceOver** turned On we see weird behavior. After setting **contentOffset** the `scrollViewDidScroll` method gets called twice. The second time it contains wrong contentOffset.x == 0 all the time.

```
func scrollToView(atIndex index: Int) {
   scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(index), y: scrollView.contentOffset.y)
}
```

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
   print("Did scroll to:\(scrollView.contentOffset.x)")
}
```

**Example with VoiceOver turned off (all good)**

`scrollToView(atIndex: 3)`

```
Did scroll to 933.0
```

**Example with VoiceOver turned on (weird behavior)**

`scrollToView(atIndex: 3)`

```
Did scroll to 933.0
Did scroll to 0.0
```

Any idea why the `scrollViewDidScroll` gets called the second time with contentOffset.x == 0 ?

Answer (score 0):

Possible (temporary) solution can be to disable accessibility element for particular moment by setting `accessibilityElementsHidden = true`